# Bootstrap 4 navbar contents shifting when opening drop down menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar creating using Bootstrap 4.3.1. It looks like this:

[image]

However when clicking on the hamburger menu to display the links, the contents of the navbar shift to the right. The BrandName moves to the right side of the content area and the search box and user icon shifts below the drop-down links, like this:

[image]

I am unable to determine what is causing these elements to shift when the drop down menu is activated.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xs fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <span class="md-blue">Brand</span>Name
        </a>
        <!-- mobile links toggle -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- mobile links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-links">
                <div class="row">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-3 pl-0">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Search box -->
        <div class="">
            <div class="input-group w-75 mx-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm md-blue-bg" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- user links toggle --> 
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- mobile: user links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="user-links">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mb-3 pl-0">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">My Account</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar { 
background-color: #1d2d4a;
padding: 0 1rem !important;
/* min-height: 70px; */
}

.navbar .btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar .login {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar .login a {
    color: #02bdf7;
}

.navbar .login a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar-brand { 
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'roundregular';
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

a:hover.navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu { 
    background-color: #1d2d4a;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .37rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .37rem;
    margin-top: 1.1rem;
    padding: 0 0 .375rem 0;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #3167eb;
}

a.dropdown-item i { font-size: 12px; }

a.nav-link { color: #fff; }
a.nav-link:hover { color: #3167eb; }

/* mobile toggles */
.navbar-toggler { 
    border: none;
    color: #fff; 
}

button.navbar-toggler i.fa { font-size: 24px; }

/* desktop menu */

/* mobile menu */
.nav-link-header {
    color: #02bdf7;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

/* navbar search */
.navbar-search-icon {
    background-color: #02bdf7;
    border: 1px solid #02bdf7
}
```

**CodePen**
[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/Pixel-Paul/pen/ExKobyj)

Comment: That is how the Bootstrap hamburger menu works - the menu is inside the navbar, so expanding it will expand the navbar too. If you want to change that behaviour, you need to be more specific about what you want it to do instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matters. The mobile links were placed above everything. That's why the other `divs` were going down when you open the menu icon and ruining the design.

So if you change the order a little bit and place the `mobile links` container  at the end of the `.container` the strange behavior will not happen. But am not sure if this how you want it to look on a big screen?

Also, you should notice there is no such class as `navbar-expand-xs` in bootstrap 4
so you should replace it by `navbar-expand-(size you want) sm - md -lg -xl`

remember if this is not the order you desire you can always use `order` and fix it.

If that didn't help please let me know and show me a screenshot of the desired output and I will do my best to help you out.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #1d2d4a;
  padding: 0 1rem !important;
  /* min-height: 70px; */
}

.navbar .btn {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar .login {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .login a {
  color: #02bdf7;
}

.navbar .login a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'roundregular';
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

a:hover.navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #1d2d4a;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .37rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .37rem;
  margin-top: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0 0 .375rem 0;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #3167eb;
}

a.dropdown-item i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

a.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
}

a.nav-link:hover {
  color: #3167eb;
}


/* mobile toggles */

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}

button.navbar-toggler i.fa {
  font-size: 24px;
}


/* desktop menu */


/* mobile menu */

.nav-link-header {
  color: #02bdf7;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}


/* navbar search */

.navbar-search-icon {
  background-color: #02bdf7;
  border: 1px solid #02bdf7
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <span class="md-blue">Brand</span>Name
    </a>
    <!-- mobile links toggle -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>

    <!-- Search box -->
    <div class="">
      <div class="input-group w-75 mx-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-sm md-blue-bg" type="submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- user links toggle -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
            </button>
    <!-- mobile: user links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="user-links">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mb-3 pl-0">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">My Account</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- mobile links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-links">
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-3 pl-0">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong at all

Only one change you need to do with collapse element that has `id="main-links"`.

You have to put your main links collapse at bottom of container.

As you can see in below example

```css
.navbar { 
    background-color: #1d2d4a;
    padding: 0 1rem !important;
    /* min-height: 70px; */
}

.navbar .btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar .login {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar .login a {
    color: #02bdf7;
}

.navbar .login a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar-brand { 
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'roundregular';
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

a:hover.navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu { 
    background-color: #1d2d4a;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .37rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .37rem;
    margin-top: 1.1rem;
    padding: 0 0 .375rem 0;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #3167eb;
}

a.dropdown-item i { font-size: 12px; }

a.nav-link { color: #fff; }
a.nav-link:hover { color: #3167eb; }

/* mobile toggles */
.navbar-toggler { 
    border: none;
    color: #fff; 
}

button.navbar-toggler i.fa { font-size: 24px; }

/* desktop menu */

/* mobile menu */
.nav-link-header {
    color: #02bdf7;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

/* navbar search */
.navbar-search-icon {
    background-color: #02bdf7;
    border: 1px solid #02bdf7
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xs fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <span class="md-blue">Brand</span>Name
        </a>
        <!-- mobile links toggle -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
      
        <!-- Search box -->
        <div class="">
            <div class="input-group w-75 mx-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm md-blue-bg" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- user links toggle --> 
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- mobile: user links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="user-links">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mb-3 pl-0">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">My Account</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
          <!-- mobile links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-links">
                <div class="row">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-3 pl-0">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Before structure**
[image]

**structure after resolved issue**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the position and display to inline helped me

```
.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after{
  position:initial !important;
  display:inline !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;  
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  width: 0px !important;
  min-width: 0rem !important;
  padding-left: 4px !important;
  margin:0ox !important;
  
}

.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]:before{
  padding-left: 4px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  position: initial !important;
  display: inline !important;  
  width: 0px !important;
  min-width: 0rem !important;  
}

a#dropdown-menu-align-right.dropdown-toggle::after{
  margin:0px !important;  
  vertical-align: initial !important;
  
}
```